# Assumptions required for an implicitely defined surface/manifold to have a specified dimension

Tags: calculus, general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

What are some normal assumptions made on implicitly defined manifolds?  More specifically, by implicitly defined manifold, I mean the definition of a surface such as

$g(x,y)=x^2+y^2-1=0$

for the surface of the unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  What I would like to have happen is to define a manifold by a function $g:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^k$ so that the resulting manifold has dimension $m=n-k$ or codimension $k$.  The problem that I'm having is that functions can do all sorts of odd things that prevent this.  For example, if $g$ defines a space filling curve, we may not restrict the space at all.  In this case, we can restrict $g$ to being differentiable and prevent this from happening.  Alternatively, it's not always clear if $g:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ peels off a single dimension.  For example, if we define

$g(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$

we only get a single point, not a 2-dimensional manifold.

As such, I'm looking for assumptions on $g:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^k$ that guarantee that we define a manifold of dimension $m-k$ or codimension $k$.

**EDIT** Notation via Fly By Night

Comment: The symbol $\Re$ is used for the real part of a complex number. If $z=x+\operatorname{i}\!y$ then $\Re(z)=x$. For the set of real numbers we use the symbol $\mathbb{R}$ or ${\bf R}$. See

http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Symbols:R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^k$ is regular at some point $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $g(x_0)=0$, then its zero-locus is a (sub)manifold of codimension $k$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (basically because of the [implicit function theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem)).

In the case of $g(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$ you have that the zero-locus is given by the single point $(0,0,0)$, where we have
$$Dg(0,0,0)=(0,0,0)^T$$
and thus $g$ is not regular there.